# PGP encrypt single message for multiple recipients

Tags: email, encryption, pgp

Is it possible to encrypt a message using PGP so that multiple recipients (each with their own public private keypair) can decrypt it? I'd like to email one message which can be decrypted by each person with their own keys.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it's possible – practically all PGP software will let you add multiple recipients when encrypting; no additional configuration is needed.

[image: Screenshot of a "recipients" window I grabbed off the googles]

Comment: Just to add, what PGP does is  generate a key for a symmetric cipher, and cipher that for each recipient with their public key. So the message for many recipients isn't much larger than that for 1.

Comment: Is there any technical limit on the number of recpients? Like a whole company of 100 people?

Comment: So the symmetric key is encrypted for each recipient with their public key. Does each receive a different ciphertext or the same ciphertext with a header length proportional to the number of recipients?

Comment: There's one copy of ciphertext and multiple copies of the same symmetric key.